# Easy to setup demo website for Sitecore 9

Tags: packages

I have installed the default version of Sitecore 9 and I want to setup a demo website on top of it.
I **DO NOT** want to install Visual studio and do code builds!

I would like to have a simple installation of a demo website through Sitecore 9 installation package.. that's it! (like the good old launchsitecore.net)

Does such exist?

Answer (score 1):

As far I know doesn't exist such a site to install a package (sitecore items, dlls) and to have a demo site up and running.

Few days ago Sitecore Demo Team create some utilities powershell scripts which helps you to install Sitecore Habitat Home Demo site

Please have a look on their github repository: https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Utilities

You will find scripts to install XP or Sitecore Commerce Habitat Home Demo Sites.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. So simple thing and in the same time so complex. I believe this this is very common scenario and it should require experienced developer to set it up.

Comment: I would say yes you need a developer unfortunately. I never seen a sales guys to run powershell scripts

Comment: Utilities is only for _installing_ Sitecore (+Commerce), not for _installing or deploying_ the Habitat Home projects.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no demo like that.

You can just install Sitecore Experience Accelerator (SXA) and create couple of simple pages with OOTB SXA components. More information here -> https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator

As a second option - Sitecore Demo team is currently working on making Habitat Home deployable via two WDP packages. This will be basically what you want.

You can check it here https://experienceplatform.habitathomedemo.com. You can use that site for demonstration purposes for now but obviously just published content. You won't get access to sitecore editors.

Check https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Content in upcoming weeks for some news.

Also check https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Content/releases maybe it will be directly there.

Meanwhile follow readme of that github repository on how  to install it via Visual Studio or follow Viet Hoang's awesome step by step guide on how to install it -> https://buoctrenmay.com/2018/08/01/sitecore-xp-9-0-2-and-sxa-1-7-1-demo-habitat-home-step-by-step-setup-guide/

Answer (score 0):

*[Cross-posted from StackOverflow where [there is a similar question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52441234/where-can-i-find-sitecore-9-demo-website)*

I realize you mentioned you already know about Habitat, but for others who come looking for an answer to this I'll drop the link to the Habitat Home repositories:

- https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Content
- https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Commerce

These allow you to tell a full end-to-end Commerce and Content experience with everything ready for you.

### Habitat Home Demo websites

The front-end of the Experience Platform demo can be viewed here: https://experienceplatform.habitathomedemo.com/

The front-end of the Experience Commerce demo can be viewed here: https://experiencecommerce.habitathomedemo.com/

### App Source

There is also a 'no installation required' demo available from App Source, but this is currently running on version 8.2 (it will be updated to 9.x in the future):

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/web-apps/sitecore.sxp_824?tab=Overview